# fadeOut() sound when Pause button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, audio, fadeout

How can I make the sound fadeout when I click the pause button?

```
<script>
var sounds = [
    "sounds/royksopp.mp3",
    "sounds/9thwonder.mp3",
    "sounds/thisbeat.mp3",
    "sounds/mosdef.mp3",
    "sounds/bewater.mp3",
    "sounds/boutdre.mp3",
    "sounds/masterflash.mp3",
    "sounds/2ep.mp3",
    "sounds/drewestcoast.mp3",
    "sounds/poetry.mp3",
    "sounds/mfdoom.mp3",
    "sounds/oizo.mp3",
];

function StartOrStop(audioFile) {
    srcAudio = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length)];
    var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    audie.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
    }, false);

    if (audie.paused == false) {
        audie.pause();
    } else {
        audie.src = srcAudio;
        audie.play();
    }
}
</script>
```

I then call it with:

```
<audio id="myAudio"></audio>

<button id="idj-play-button" onclick="StartOrStop()" class="btn btn-lg"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i>
</button>

<button id="idj-pause-button" onclick="StartOrStop()" class="btn btn-lg hide"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
</button>
```

Do I need to change something on my If/Else statement `audie.pause()`? I've tried `audie.animate({volume: 0}, 1000);` but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: To use `.animate` you need the audio to be a jQuery element: `$(audie).animate(...)`

Comment: If I use `$(audie).animate({volume: 0}, 500);` instead of `audie.pause();` it successfully lowers the volume to 0, but when I click the play button again, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   <script>
    var sounds = [
        "sounds/royksopp.mp3",
        "sounds/9thwonder.mp3",
        "sounds/thisbeat.mp3",
        "sounds/mosdef.mp3",
            "sounds/bewater.mp3",
            "sounds/boutdre.mp3",
            "sounds/masterflash.mp3",
            "sounds/2ep.mp3",
        "sounds/drewestcoast.mp3",
            "sounds/poetry.mp3",
            "sounds/mfdoom.mp3",
        "sounds/dreams.mp3",
        "sounds/oizo.mp3", ];

    function Start(audioFile) {
        srcAudio = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*sounds.length)];
        var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
        audie.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
        }, false);

                $(audie).animate({volume: 0.9}, 0);
                audie.src = srcAudio;
                audie.play();

          }

    function Stop(audioFile) {
        var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");

                $(audie).animate({volume: 0}, 400);

          }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<audio id="myAudio"></audio>

<button id="idj-play-button" onclick="Start()" class="btn btn-lg"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i>
</button>

<button id="idj-pause-button" onclick="Stop()" class="btn btn-lg hide"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`audie.animate({volume: 0}, 1000);` would work only when you have jQuery.

You could make the changes like this:

```
if (audie.paused == false) {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (audie.volume == 0) {
             audie.pause();
             clearInterval(interval);
        }
        audie.volume -= 0.05; 
    }, 800);
}
```

Comment: Hi, when I click the pause button it lowers the volume but still appears to be audible, very very low. And when I click again the play button, nothing happens.